# why is cloudflare blocking my wordpress page

Tags: wordpress, parsing, cross-domain, cloudflare

I have a wordpress site:
http://www.fairlady-sleepingtiger.co.uk/
but the home page is not displaying all the content.

When I inspect the Console I see this message:

```
www.fairlady-sleepingtiger.co.uk/:12 A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=088620b277/cloudflare.min.js, is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if the device has poor network connectivity.
```

I have deleted/disbaled all Cloudflare functionality from this site but this still comes up.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

You are still pointing to Cloudflare nameservers, so your domain is still being proxied.

There is a period of time where we will continue to handle DNS even after you remove your zone, which protects against this situation where the nameservers didn't get changed.  Otherwise the site would just be unreachable.

If you want to completely remove Cloudflare you need to update the nameservers at your registrar, and depending on the registrar it should update in 24 hours or so.